# Possible to use server for collecting and distributing mail

Tags: email, pop3

We currently have POP3 mail accounts where I am and try as I might to convince my manager that we should be using hosted IMAP or Exchange he won't budge because of the cost. The staff are mostly out of office so there is no domain server here, however, we do have a dedicated server and I wondered whether I could use this to collect the mail and distribute it from there in some way.

Effectively what I'm trying to do is ensure mail is stored somewhere other than the end users machine because backups are user dependant at the moment.  With hosted Exchange or Exchange on this server would be simple but my manager won't shell out for it.  I have seen free mail servers called MailEnable and Axigen but unsure if they will do the job.  Sorry if this seems like an easy or stupid question but never needed to do this before.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming due to the reference to Exchange that you are on Windows.

If you have an old box lying around that works, you could install linux on it and then choose from a number of different imap servers. Dovecot and Courier are both good choices and I have worked with them before.

You could use fetchmail to then pick up the mailboxes and then deliver to the imap boxes or get them deliver directly.

Setting up such a linux server for email was one of the first things I ever did on Linux. While initially daunting, once you get the hang of it, it is pretty straightforward and there are plenty of resources out there to help.

Ubuntu is probably the easiest to get used to. CentOs is also a reasonable choice.

Comment: Yes, the solution needs to be Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be running your own server if you aren't willing to administer your own server, and they are *not* easy to configure if you don't know what you are doing (e.g., you mess up and you are exploited for spamming).

Look into a service like [mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/).  In my application we are using them for forwarding to REST endpoints as well as onto another SMTP server.

Competitors that wound up not meeting my needs but may meet yours include Dyn, email yak, Sendgrid, etc. etc.

Comment: I don't want to use another provider or create an application to handle the mail.  I want to keep the current provider and still allow end users to use Outlook etc to send/recieve as before.  But I want to put our dedicated server in the middle so the end user send/recieves to this and the server sends/recieves from the provider, does this make sense?

Comment: @user1166905 it does make sense, and have fun.  I recommend ordering a book on Exim.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just setup the mail clients to store their mail files on a standard network drive or share?  I follow that this situation is pretty silly in your view - 100% because of the ridiculous constraints that you are being asked to work within: I would similarly find the solution I am suggesting ridiculous generally; but under the circumstances, it seems like a simple answer to your problem - replacing distributed mail storage and backup with centralized storage and backup.

Comment: @user1166905, i.e. expose a share on the available dedicated server you mention in your question - FWIW.

Comment: @user1166905, I apologize for not considering sooner the implications of staff that are mostly remote: my suggestion could straightforwardly accommodate local staff, but remote staff would have to connect by VPN to use the share of course.  Maybe a reasonable approach (under the circumstances) is to keep the remote users' mail local to their machines...but one-way sync their PST files to the share when they connect by VPN to still centralize mail for backup as best as possible.  If the remote users don't connect by VPN, forget it (without a lot of custom work you don't want to do).

Answer (score -1):

Don't POP3 email clients have the option keep a copy on the server? Mine certainly does. See second tick box on the pic.[image: email]

You can then periodically take a back up of all the emails from the server to stop it getting clogged up.

Comment: The provider only allows to keep minimum space so after a period of time we would get charged for being over the storage limit